# Why does WolframAlpha give different answers for these two equivalent limits?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Here are two limits with different answers provided by Wolfram|Alpha:

[Limit 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20z%20tends%20to%20((2-i)%2F5)%20of%202(z-(2-i)%2F5)%2F((1-2i)z%5E2%2B(6i)z%2B(-2i-1))):

$$\lim_{z\to \frac{2}{5}-\frac{i}{5}} \frac{2\left(z-\frac{2-i}{5}\right)}{(1-2i)z^2+(6i)z+(-2i-1)}=-\frac{i}{2}$$

[Limit 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20z%20tends%20to%20((2-i)%2F5)%20of%202(z-(2-i)%2F5)%2F%5B(z-((2-i)%2F5))(z-(2-i))%5D):

$$\lim_{z\to \frac{2}{5}-\frac{i}{5}} \frac{2\left(z-\frac{2-i}{5}\right)}{\left(z-\frac{2-i}{5}\right)\left(z-(2-i)\right)}=-1-\frac{i}{2}$$

Aren't these the same limits because $(1-2i)z^2+(6i)z+(-2i-1)=\left(z-\frac{2-i}{5}\right)\left(z-(2-i)\right)$?

Here is what [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-2i)z%5E2%2B(6i)z%2B(-2i-1)) suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The two denominators are not equal : notice that they don't have the same coefficient for $z^2$. Instead, you should have (according to the $3$rd link) the equality
$$(1-2i)z^2+(6i)z+(-2i-1)=(1-2i)\left(z-\frac{2-i}{5}\right)\left(z-(2-i)\right),$$
so the two limits only differ from a factor $1-2i$. Then the results become coherent, as indeed,
$$-\frac{i}{2}\left(1-2i\right)=-1-\frac{i}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm a little confused as to why that equality you've written is true. If the roots of $(1-2i)z^2+(6i)z+(-2i-1)$ are $(2-i)/5$ and $(2-i)$ then can't we just factorise it as I've written in the first post? Where does the $(1-2i)$ come from?

Comment: Your factorisation is wrong, because you have forgotten to take into account the leading coefficient. This leading coefficient is the $(1-2i)$.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit slow but it's not quite clicking. Is it not true that if you find the roots of $f(z)$ to be $z=a$ and $z=b$, then you may write $f(z)=(z-a)(z-b)$? In this case with $f(z):=(1-2i)z^2+(6i)z+(-2i-1)$, $a=(2-i)/5$ and $b=(2-i)$. I see that the $(1-2i)$ term is missing but don't understand why?

Comment: @Alex.F: the function $f(z)$ and $2\cdot f(z)$ have the same roots. Are you saying that they necessarily equal?

Comment: @WillieWong Ah I think I get it now. So if $f(z)$ has roots $a$ and $b$ then $f(z)=c(z-a)(z-b)$ for some multiplicative constant $c$. Usually $c=1$ but not always, which is what I misunderstood. Right?

Comment: @Alex.F I wouldn't really say "usually", but that's right.